# Display message box on CTRL + ALT + DEL

Tags: vbscript

I want to display a message to the user when they try to lock the computer using `CTRL + ALT + DEL`, when they see the message then they will click OK and the computer will lock. How could I accomplish something like this? I have looked around but have found no solution.

Comment: VB.NET and VBScript are quite different. Which is it?

Comment: I'm sorry VBScript. I'm still learning the language. I'm not looking for the exact solution, I just want to know what steps I need to take to accomplish the task. Thanks

Comment: No need to apologise I just wanted to suggest you remove one tag or the other.

Comment: what im looking for is some sort of script file that I can pass to a few coworkers with a text reminder on the desktop before they lock the machine, I've been learning the language for this, and this is my ideas for when I'm ready to code it, first I have to capture the ctrl alt del combination, then I need to display the message, and then let the computer lock the computer, is there anything else I need to add?

Comment: and no its not a duplicate, that other question provides no solution whatsoever to my question, besides the links in the "possible" answer are dead.

Comment: @Alex Please re-read the answer Shog9 provided for that other question (including the comments). Once you fully grasp what that answer's telling you, you'll understand why your question *is* a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

You CAN'T. It is designed to prevent you doing that. No windows function supports CAD. It's about preventing password capturing.

And the reason we press those keys is that the IBM keyboard designer refused MS request for a special purpose key for logon.

From WSDK
Initializing Winlogon
When Winlogon initializes, it registers the CTRL+ALT+DEL secure attention sequence (SAS) with the system, and then creates three desktops within the WinSta0 window station.

Registering CTRL+ALT+DEL makes this initialization the first process, thus ensuring that no other application has hooked that key sequence.